# Problems Using New Firebase 9.0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am doing a Udemy course where we are attempting to build an e-commerce site.
The course uses Firebase V6 but I discovered that a very different more modular V9 was just released. I decided that the new modular system would be better to learn and I attempted to use this to achieve the same results as the course in one of my personal projects.

I was able to add data to the Firestore database but am now attempting to create snapshots and work from them and am having some issues.

Here is my Firebase.utils component

```
const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp);
const usersCollectionRef = collection(db, 'users');


const createUserProfileDocument = async (userAuth, aditionalData) => {
    if (!userAuth) return;
    const userRef = doc(db, `users/${userAuth.uid}`);
    console.log(userAuth.uid);
    const docSnap = await getDoc(userRef);
    
    if (!docSnap.exists()) {
        const { displayName, email } = userAuth;
        const createdAt = new Date();
       
    
        try {
          await setDoc(userRef,  {
            displayName,
            email,
            createdAt,
            // ...additionalData
          });
        } catch (error) {
          console.log('error creating user', error.message);
        }
      }
      console.log('test');
      console.log(userRef);
      console.log(docSnap.exists());
      console.log(docSnap.data());
      console.log(userAuth.uid);
      return userRef;
    
    }
    
const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
provider.setCustomParameters({
    prompt: 'select_account'
});

const auth = getAuth();


    const google = async () => {
        signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
            .then((result) => {
                // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
                const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
                const token = credential.accessToken;
                // The signed-in user info.
                const user = result.user;
                // ...
            }).catch((error) => {
                // Handle Errors here.
                const errorCode = error.code;
                const errorMessage = error.message;
                // The email of the user's account used.
                const email = error.email;
                // The AuthCredential type that was used.
                const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromError(error);
                // ...
            });
    }
```

This seems to work well. It Authenticates my user and sets a doc as I want it.

My problem occurs when I try to add the following code to my App.js component:

```
 const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    let unsubscribeFromAuth = null;
    unsubscribeFromAuth = onAuthStateChanged(async userAuth => {
      if (userAuth) {
        
        const userRef = await createUserProfileDocument(userAuth);
        onSnapshot(userRef, (docSnap) => {
          console.log(docSnap.data());
          setCurrentUser({
            id: docSnap.id,
            ...docSnap.data()
          }); 
        })
      } else {
        setCurrentUser({userAuth});
      }
      return () => {
        unsubscribeFromAuth();
      }
    })
  },[]);
```

This is the error I receive

[image]

I feel like I'm really close to the solution here but I'm doing something minor wrong. Any help or advice would be great, thanks.

I have changed my code to this

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let unsubscribeFromAuth = null;
    unsubscribeFromAuth = auth.onAuthStateChanged(async userAuth => {
      if (userAuth) {
        const userRef = await createUserProfileDocument(userAuth);
        console.log('ur: ' + userRef);
        onSnapshot(doc(db, `users/${userAuth.uid}`), docSnap => {
          setCurrentUser({
            id: docSnap.id,
            ...docSnap.data()
          }); 
        })
      }
    })
  });
```

Comment: Can you `console.log(userRef)` before `onSnapshot` and share the output ?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help @Dharmaraj, I know the question is confusing as I am very confused myself.
When I console.log userRef it returns [object, object].

Comment: I would directly add the the userRef in onSnapshot like this: `onSnapshot(doc(db, `users/${userAuth.uid}`))`. Before that the `createUserProfileDocument` would take care of creating the docs.

Comment: @Dharmaraj I have added an edit to the end of my original post. Unfortunately this code gives me a new error
'Unhandled Rejection (FirebaseError): Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore'

Comment: Is the `db` defined for sure? Also try `doc(db, 'users', userAuth.uid)`

Comment: @Dharmaraj If I console.log db before onSnaphot it also gives me [object object].
If I right click on db in my App.js component and select 'go to definition' it takes me to my firebase component where I used const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp);.
I also tried making the other change and it still wants a collectionRef etc.

Answer (score 0):

In this part:

```js
nsubscribeFromAuth = onAuthStateChanged(async userAuth => {
      if (userAuth) {
```

you forgot to put `auth` as first param:

```js
                                       // here
nsubscribeFromAuth = onAuthStateChanged(auth,async userAuth => {
      if (userAuth) {
```

Comment: @TarikHubber Thanks, but unfortunately that gives me the original error.
Expected type Ic but it was an object.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import FormInput from "../form-input/form-input.component";
import CustomButton from "../custom-button/custom-button.component";

import { auth, createUserProfileDocument } from "../../firebase/firebase.utils";
import "./sign-up.styles.scss";
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";

const SignUp = () => {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState({
    displayName: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    confirmPassword: ""
  });

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const { displayName, email, password, confirmPassword } = currentUser;

    if (password !== confirmPassword) {
      alert("passwords don't match");
      return;
    }

    try {
      const { user } = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        auth,
        email,
        password
      );

      await createUserProfileDocument(user, { displayName });

      setCurrentUser({
        displayName: "",
        email: "",
        password: "",
        confirmPassword: ""
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;

    setCurrentUser((prevValue) => {
      return { ...prevValue, [name]: value };
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="sign-up">
      <h2 className="title">I do not have a account</h2>
      <span>Sign up with your email and password</span>
      <form className="sign-up-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <FormInput
          type="text"
          name="displayName"
          value={currentUser.displayName}
          onChange={handleChange}
          label="Display Name"
          required
        />
        <FormInput
          type="email"
          name="email"
          value={currentUser.email}
          onChange={handleChange}
          label="Email"
          required
        />
        <FormInput
          type="password"
          name="password"
          value={currentUser.password}
          onChange={handleChange}
          label="Password"
          required
        />
        <FormInput
          type="password"
          name="confirmPassword"
          value={currentUser.confirmPassword}
          onChange={handleChange}
          label="Confirm Password"
          required
        />
        <CustomButton type="submit">SIGN UP</CustomButton>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SignUp;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please describe, highlight and clarify any changes you made to the code by adding a short introduction and by using more code blocks as needed (similar to what Tarik did in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69188476/3068190)). In its current form, finding what you changed would be akin to finding a needle in a haystack.